# Library conflict when running AppEngine using PyCharm

Tags: google-app-engine, pycharm

I am trying to run AppEngine Standard Environment inside PyCharm.
The problem is when I include Google App Engine SDK as part of External Libraries, but it contains multiple version of old libraries that somehow has higher priority than the library I have in my env folder.

Specifically, it is loading jinja2-2.6 which doesn't work for Python 3, even though I have jinja2-2.11.3 in my env/lib.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pycharm does have a bit of issues with its library system as many users have reported before.  To Adjust the version of your libraries in PyCharm you must access the interpreter options relating your python interpreter for your current project, you can access this option by searching in the menu `Settings/Preferences` or by pressing `Ctrl+Alt+S`

In this dialog you can view the packages available and their current running versions. You can update the version by clicking on the ▲ symbol next to the version. if you have trouble upgrading to a specific version you may need then you can alway remove a package by clicking on the "-" on the right hand side after clicking on the package you wish to remove. After removing the package you can add a new one by clicking on the "+" button right on top of the "-" button. Here you can search for the package you need and before installing a package, you can check the specific version checkbox to search for the version you require in the dropdown menu next to it.

This [link](https://www.datasciencelearner.com/how-to-install-jinja-in-pycharm/) contains images for what i'm explaining here.

Remember that these packages are taken directly from the pip so if you have errors using the interface you can always try to manually edit the packages (also described in the link).

To upgrade a specific package using pip for python3 you can use the following command:

```
pip3 install --upgrade PackageName
```

Comment: After digging around a bit more I found out that Pycharm has an important note regarding versioning.

`Note that PyCharm always uses the Python 2.7 runtime when creating a new project. `

I believe this is the reason why GAE SDK tries to use older libraries, this is mostly because of how Pycharm creates GAE projects. Until the IntelliJ team updates this creation process I dont think GAE SDK will update the external libraries.

[note_link](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/creating-google-app-engine-project.html)